# Select an element behind a div on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `select` element that looks like this:

[image]

The arrow in there is a custom element. I'd like to make it so that the error is "invisible" to the mouse, and clicking it will actually select the element behind it. I tried using `onClick` on the arrow to `focus()` the `select`, but that doesn't actually initiate the dropdown menu:

[image]

Is there some kind of CSS magic trick that'll let me do this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

> `none`
> The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value.
>
> source: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)